# How can a lambda expression have access to objects from the global scope?

Tags: java

I have working code:

```
public int myFunc(int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
    for (int a : arr)
        count.put(a, 1 + count.getOrDefault(a, 0));
    
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparing(count::get));
    // .....
}
```

How come the comparator can see and utilize `count`? What feature of the language is being used here?

To my knowledge, if you need to use a variable inside a method (the comparator), the variable needs to be either a 1) parameter of the method or, 2) defined in the Object itself or, 3) defined in the global scope. Here, `count` is just a local variable. So clearly I’m missing something.

Comment: `if you need to use a variable inside a method (the comparator), the variable needs to be either a 1) parameter of the method or, 2) defined in the Object itself or, 3) defined in the global scope.` Where did you read that from?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking about the implementation details of how method references can capture local variables, or are you asking about which sections of the language specification allow this?

Comment: There is no "global scope". There is a narrowly-defined surrounding scope.

Comment: @Sweeper maybe a reference to the specification? Maybe I should’ve clarified in my question. The 3 enumerations I listed is what I have experienced and I wasn’t aware there were more ways to capture variables :)

Answer (score 0):

The Comparator.comparing static function accepts a sort key Function and returns a Comparator for the type which contains the sort key:

```
static <T,U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
   Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

Here we are passing a method reference, which is accesible across

https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing